# How to assign numbers to/rank text in cells and display the lowest or highest within a list?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel document report back on the worst condition of a single part from a number of different parts in an assembly. For example, if I have an assembly that is made up of three parts; one part was in good condition, another fair condition and the third was in poor condition; the overall condition of the assembly would be poor because it will only be as good as its worst part.

I can do this if I had a list of numbers by simply using the min function, but I am not sure how to do this efficiently with text. I have thought of grading the conditions by assigning numbers to them. For example, let's assume I have the following information:

```
A1: Part 1                 B1: Good
A2: Part 2                 B2: Fair
A3: Part 3                 B3: Poor
```

I could enter:

```
C1: =IF(B1="Good",3,IF(B1="Fair",2,IF(B1="Poor",1)))"
C2: =IF(B2="Good",3,IF(B2="Fair",2,IF(B2="Poor",1)))"
C3: =IF(B3="Good",3,IF(B3="Fair",2,IF(B3="Poor",1)))"
C4: =MIN(C1,C2,C3)"
C5: ="Overall condition is "&IF(C4=3"Good",If(C4=2,"Fair",IF(C4=1,"Poor")
```

The problem with this is it is spread over 5 different cells and is quite messy. I'm also not able to highlight what part is in the worst condition (I need the cell number and the cell text)

Would anyone be able to offer some advice on how I could do this all in one cell?

Answer (score 1):

use an Array formula ...

enter in C1: `=MIN(IF(B1:B3="Good",3,IF(B1:B3="Fair",2,1)))`

finish with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>